# NSDateFormatter to NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
NSDate *dateNow = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"NSDate                : %@", dateNow);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNow];
NSLog(@"NSDateFormatter String: %@", dateString);

NSDate *dateObject = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"NSDateFormatter Object: %@", dateObject);
```

First off ignore the 1970-01-01 I am only interested in the time for now.

My question is when I get the time from NSDate it does not include any time zone information. This is what I expected so the time returned from NSDate is 01:21:57 PM. To correct this I am using NSDateFormatter and setting its locale, it correctly interprets that I am in London, British Summer Time (GMT+01). Finally I want to get the new corrected date back as an NSDate so I use dateFromString on the previously correct dateString.

Can anyone tell me why the resultant date reverts back to being uncorrected (i.e. 01:21:57 PM) is there anyway that I can do this conversion and still maintain the specified locale / timeZone?

```
>> WALL_CLOCK: 02:21:57 PM
>> NSDate                : 2011-04-08 01:21:57 PM +0000
>> NSDateFormatter String: 02:21:57 PM GMT+01:00
>> NSDateFormatter Object: 1970-01-01 01:21:57 PM +0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All NSDate objects are stored as seconds since the reference date (Jan 1 2001 00:00 GMT) and so are always GMT+0.

Comment: so if I do need to go back to an NSDate for whatever reason I would need to use another NSDateFormatter to adjust for the locale to output the correct time?

Comment: Basically every time you need to display the date and or time to a view, you would need the NSDateFormatter.  If you have lots of conversion, you could just create an ivar of NSDateFormatter in your controller init.  Don't forget to release in your dealloc.  :)

Comment: Yup yup got it, I see how it works. So what happens if your comparing to a known NSDate date/time with a current NSDate from iOS, do you just specify the known date at GMT+0 do the calculation (i.e. how many hours since) and then us NSDateFormatter to convert to the current locale. Does that make sense?

Comment: One final point it I may, you can't bake the timeZone into an NSDate, its always something that you have to compensate for before output using NSDateFormatter, does that sound right?

Comment: NSDateFormatter will default to the current system timezone until you change it. So if you have a date string '2011-04-08 11:00 EST' it will be converted to GMT when saved to NSDate object. And the current NSDate from iOS is in GMT.

Answer (score 0):

In your code. You only provided the format for the Locale and Time. You didn't provide a format for the Date, therefore you got the default result: 1970-01-01

```
NSDate *dateNow = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"NSDate                : %@", dateNow);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNow];
NSLog(@"NSDateFormatter String: %@", dateString);

NSDate *dateObject = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"NSDateFormatter Object: %@", dateObject);
```

Output:

```
2011-04-08 10:12:39.119 test[2957:207] NSDate                : 2011-04-08 14:12:39 +0000
2011-04-08 10:12:39.121 test[2957:207] NSDateFormatter String: April 8, 2011 10:12:39 AM EDT
2011-04-08 10:12:39.123 test[2957:207] NSDateFormatter Object: 2011-04-08 14:12:39 +0000
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, that is true and I mentioned that at the top of the text. However that is something I chose not to do, my question was with regards to the face that when I did dateFromString (on the localised GMT+01) string it went back to being un-localised (i.e. GMT).