# NSDateFormatter -- Not getting the correct formatter string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdateformatter

I am getting a wrong formatted date string returned by NSDateFormatter. Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *aDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[aDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *aFormattedElapsedTime = [aDateFormatter stringFromDate:refDate];
```

Here,
refDate (NSDate object) = 1970-01-01 00:36:22 +0000

Output I am getting is "16h:36m:22s" instead of "00h:36m:22s".

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: refDate is passed to stringFromDate so I assume it's a string, can you give us the exact string you are using?

Comment: What time zone are you in, you probably need to specify the time zone of your formatter, looks like it is using a -8 timezone so my guess is you live on the west coast.

Comment: @Joe: You are right. I am in west coast. Now, I get the correct difference if I set the time zone to GMT. My confusion is that are we getting date in GMT format always when we use dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 method of NSDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the timezone. (See my comment above)

```
NSDateFormatter *aDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[aDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]
[aDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *aFormattedElapsedTime = [aDateFormatter stringFromDate:refDate];
```

Answer (score 2):

NSDateFormatter will default to current time zone on the system unless you set it with  `setTimeZone`.

```
[aDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Take a look at [NSDateFormatter to NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595848/nsdateformatter-to-nsstring/5595915#5595915)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from living in Pacific Time, not really. Add your timezone offset in there and you'll understand why you're getting that value: `NSDateFormatter` is formatting the date as interpreted in local time, not `UTC`.